# xcode loading 2 view controllers on top of each other on button trigger

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

this is the first time I am seeing this... it seems that when I trigger the segue to the settingsViewController xcode is loading 2 View controllers on top of each other.  The View controller with the byDate and byCategory buttons is part of a page view controller and I don't understand why this is happening.

Here is a photo of my storyboard:  the settings VC is the one above Add New Transaction and the summary VC loads view controllers as the DataSource of a UIPageViewController

[image]

Here is my result:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to tell with this information what's causing this problem, but your storyboard has other problems. You should not go backwards to previous controllers with a segue, unless you use an unwind segue. That doesn't "go back", it creates new instances of the controller you think you're going back to.

Comment: I didn't know that. thanks for the info. how can i set up an unwind segue?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them/15839298#15839298